# Foreach loop through an array of JSON from an API

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I'm creating a stock market portfolio website with the use of the IEX API but I'm currently stuck on one part when it comes to retrieving data as an array and then storing the values in a table.

Here's the code:

```
$div = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=F,AAPL&types=stats&filter=dividendRate");  
$div = json_decode($div,TRUE);  

foreach($div as $divi => $value)
echo '<br/>'. $divi.' : '. $value;

var_dump($div);
```

What I'm getting now is this:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   E:\XAMPP\htdocs\website2\test.php on line 34

F : Array

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   E:\XAMPP\htdocs\website2\test.php on line 34

AAPL : Array

From the var_dump, I get this:

> array(2) { ["F"]=> array(1) { ["stats"]=> array(1) {
>   ["dividendRate"]=> float(0.13) } } ["AAPL"]=> array(1) { ["stats"]=>
>   array(1) { ["dividendRate"]=> float(2.52) } } }

And essentially, I want to have the dividend amount displayed instead of the word 'array', next to the symbols, in a table- what am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: The error message is crystal clear, isn't it? `F` holds an _array. You cannot simply `echo` an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to further reference the right array elements to get this value in your loop...

```
foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
    echo '<br/>'. $divi.' : '. $value['stats']['dividendRate'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the var_dump, this data is an array of arrays of arrays. When you try to echo an array, it will only output the string 'Array'. Specify the keys of the elements of that array to get to the actual data.

```
foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
    echo $divi . ':' . $value['stats']['dividendRate'];
}
```

This is data formatted.

```
array(2) {
    ["F"]=> array(1) { 
        ["stats"]=> array(1) {
            ["dividendRate"]=> float(0.13) 
        }
    } 
    ["AAPL"]=> array(1) { 
        ["stats"]=> array(1) { 
            ["dividendRate"]=> float(2.52) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.